# In MVC, how do I pass in form data as query strings?

Tags: c#, search, model-view-controller, query-string

I want to make it so that when people search for something, what they searched gets added to the url of the next page. So they can favorite the page, and then access the page again without filling in the  form again. All the posts I can fine assume I want to pass in hard coded query string parameters.

Comment: You can simply decorate your controller method  with HttpGet and pass string with in id parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When you send an HTTP POST request, the data that the client send to the server are stored in the request's body.

While, when you send an HTTP GET request, you can send data to the client that are in the query string (after the question mark, ?, in form of key/value pairs, `?name=test&age=21`) of your url.

That being said, you have to add a filter to your `ActionResult` method in your controller that allows only HTTP GET request to reach it. For instance, you need something like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ActionName(string name, int age)
    {
    }
}
```

Then the client can make a GET request using the following url:

```
www.domain/Home/ActionName?name=test&age=21
```